# quotes turn into backslashes with Deno.Command

Tags: typescript, windows, cmd, spotify, deno

```
await new Deno.Command('cmd', {
    args: [
        '/c',
        'start',
        `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${new URLSearchParams({
            client_id,
            response_type: 'code',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/callback',
            scope: 'user-library-read',
        })}`.replaceAll(/&/g, '"&"'),
    ],
    stdout: 'piped',
    stderr: 'piped',
}).output();
```

I am trying to open this URL in my browser in Deno on Windows. However, the URL that is opened is this:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=x\&\response_type=code\&\redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fcallback\&\scope=user-library-read
```

where the `"` has been replaced with `\`. If I do not wrap the `&` in the URL parameters in quotes, then only one URL parameter gets opened in the browser like this:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=x
```

I would like to open the URL in the browser with all parameters but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

https://deno.land/api@v1.35.3?s=Deno.CommandOptions#prop_windowsRawArguments
There's a flag to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Consider accepting this answer by clicking the checkmark in the left hand side of it.

Comment: thanks, but it's telling me that i can accept my own answer in 2 days